# Rails Bootstrap button_to not showing link in statusbar when hovering

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I have a rails 5.0.1 application with Bootstrap4 alpha6.

I have a button_to link on my page.

```
<%= 
  button_to "Edit Chapter",
  edit_chapter_path(chapter),
  method: :get, 
  class: "btn btn-success" 
%>
```

When I hover over this link, the mouse does not change it's cursor to a pointer. Also the link preview in the status bar on chrome does not show.

I have fixed the pointer issue by adding to my `application.scss`

```
.btn {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

How can I restore the functionality of the link being shown in the status bar?

I can confirm that it works on my `link_to` links in the app. Just anything with the `button_to` does not work.

Comment: you can wrap button with `link_to` and add `href` on `link_to`

Comment: rails docs says to use button_to when sending actions. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to.  'This is the safest method to ensure links that cause changes to your data are not triggered by search bots or accelerators.'

Comment: first thing first  button_to will create new form with specified `URL` and submit button so its not allow to display link in status bar.http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to

Comment: Ok cool, thanks for that explanation. I'll do with what I have then :)

Comment: Cheers! Happy coding